# JavaScript can't reach the weather API

Tags: javascript

I just want to code a simple weather app for learning JS. I can't find the mistake after searching the whole web...

I don't get any information from the API. I checked this in the browser console.

I just want to show the current weather conditions from LA.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector(".temperature-description");
  let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector(".temperature-degree");
  let locationTimezone = document.querySelector(".location-timezone");

  const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  const api = '${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/4d5ddfbfc8eabb0dddcb9e78fb408a99/37.8267,-122.4233';

  fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      const {
        temperature,
        summary
      } = data.currently;

      temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature;
      temperatureDescription.textContent = summary;
      locationTimezone.textContent = data.timezone;
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer helped out and solved your issue, press the checkbox next to the answer to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just from a quick overview it seems like you're using the wrong quotation marks.

Try putting your API variable into ``` `` ``` instead of `''`.

Comment: Yeah, also use `encodeURIComponent()` around the URL rather than just sticking it at the end of the proxy URL.

Comment: oh my gosh... I'm so sorry...
Thanks a lot!